# does not show simple Action bar in android app

Tags: android-actionbar

I am trying to make an action bar in my app. I have already hide the default action bar but it is not showing my action bar.

I am using code from :-
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_category, menu);
            return true;
            }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

 }
```

here is code for menu:-

Comment: Show some code of what you have tried

Comment: please check i have added some code